# Error installing pyautogui package via offline mode

Tags: installation, subprocess, pyautogui

Need to install pyautogui via offline environment (prod) to make the automation work as I need to compile hundred of scripts with different parameters from different assets.

I have installed some other packages such pyinstaller, pywinauto etc. However, I encountered errors when going through with pyautogui.

Via offline mode, I cant seem to direct install pip package.name.
Usually, what I do is using BULK RENAME. Through my own local device, I would download the packages in a new folder, using Bulk Rename Utility, Ill copy & paste the filename into requirements.txt and run this command in the offline environment later.

```
pip install --no-index --find-links .\ -r requirements.txt
```

But as for pyautogui, this is my first time encountering this error as below.

[image: errors during installation]

Anyone has encounter this error before? if so, please advise.

Thanks!